# How to check if a reflected type is an array

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, typeof

I'm using reflection to read in an xml file and keep coming across an error telling me that I cannot convert a string to a string[] (which I don't want to do!) I think the cause of my problem is I'm unable to tell if the type of the object is an array or not. Below is what I'm currently using (doesn't work right) but I've also tried to use `if(mi[i].GetType() == typeof(string[]))` which also doesnt work..

```
MemberInfo[] mi = objType.GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < mi.Length; i++)
{
  if (mi[i].GetType().IsArray)
  {
  }
  else
  {
   //Code path is running through here
  }
```

The file is read in correctly..

EDIT: I thought I'd better add the structure to my `objType` to better explain..

`objType` is a class that contains a string[] variable that in this case is referred to as `mi[i]`

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to check `objType.IsArray` instead?

Comment: The type of `mi[i]` is `MemberInfo`. [MemberInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.aspx) is not an array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've updated my question to better explain

Comment: mi should be of type `PropertyInfo[]` in order to get access to the `Propertytype` property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `PropertyType` rather than `GetType()` on the `MemberInfo` to get the underlying type of the property.

```
var mi = objType.GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < mi.Length; i++)
{
    var type = mi[i].PropertyType;
    //Check for string array
    if (type.IsArray && type.GetElementType() == typeof(string))
    {
    }
}
```

Or you can do

```
if(type == typeof(string[]))
{
}
```

Comment: But he uses `type.IsArray` and it never enters the `if`.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Yes, it should be `mi[i].PropertyType` not `mi[i].GetType()`.

Comment: PropertyType isn't available to me?

Comment: msdn for memberinfo - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx

Comment: I found where property type resides and this was correct
`objType.GetProperty(mi[i].Name).PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string[]))`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: mi should be of type `PropertyInfo[]` in order to get access to the `Propertytype` property